# Why is my column maxing out at 282px width instead of 660px?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need this column to be full-width, which is 660px.

Other sections function correctly, but I removed them from the below code to make the code block "minimal." I cannot determine the difference between functioning sections and this non-functioning section. I need to fix this first (in the most fundamental/basic way for email client compatibility) and I need to understand this second.

- There is no CSS indicating specific width or percentage.
- There is no parent element indicating this width.
- Other sections that to my eye look completely identical are appropriately full width.
- Inspecting on Chrome shows 282 width, but does not indicate why. [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umoFk.jpg)
- Even when I set the width with HTML to 100% or 660, the browser ignores this and keeps it at 282.
- If a single unbroken string of text extends beyond 282, the entire template stretches out horizontally to keep the column in proportion.

Below is the entire unfinished template. There is a lot of extra CSS which I will cull later with an Inspect audit, but there is no indication that any of that styling is touching these TD.

The document is for a one-column e-mail template.

Does anybody have any ideas?

```css
/* General Formatting */

body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  color: #333333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  border: 0;
}
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.webkit {
  max-width: 660px;
  Margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer {
  Margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 660px;
  background: white;
}
/* Header */

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}
.header img {
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.header .contents {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #4b3c30;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.header .logo {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.header .social {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header .monthly {
  padding: 0px;
}
.hero {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #4b3c30;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #4b3c30;
  font-size: 15px;
}
/* Body */

.category {
  text-align: left;
  color: #e14c25 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.title {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #e14c25 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.time {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #e14c25 !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.price {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #e14c25 !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.full-width-image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 660px;
  height: auto;
}
.text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: #4b3c30;
}
a {
  color: #e14c25;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.one-column .contents {
  text-align: center;
}
.one-column .navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.three-column {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.three-column .column {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.first-two {
  padding-right: 30px !important;
}
.third {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.three-column .contents {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
.three-column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
/* Caption and Credits */

.caption {
  color: #999999;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}
/* Footer */

#footer {
  background: #cfcac6;
}
#footer .contents {
  color: #4b3c30;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.two-column .column1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.two-column a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.two-column .column2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.two-column .contents {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .navbar {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .navbar a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .three-column .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .three-column img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .header .logo {
    max-width: 45% !important;
  }
  .header .logo .lockup {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .header .monthly {
    width: 68%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .first-two {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 670px) {
  .three-column .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .three-column img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .header .logo {
    max-width: 45% !important;
  }
  .header .logo .lockup {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .header .monthly {
    width: 68%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .first-two {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- JUST FOR OUTLOOK-->
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
            .one-column a {font-size: 18px !important; color: #e14c25 !important;}
            .three-column a {font-size: 18px !important; color: #e14c25 !important;}
            .three-column img {width:200 height:200}
            .two-column a {color: white !important; font-size: 11px !important; font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important}
            .title img {width: 200px; height: auto;}   
        </style>
        <![endif]-->


<center class="wrapper">
  <div class="webkit">
    <p style="text-align: center;" class="social"><a style="color: rgb(225, 76, 37); font-size: 11px;" target="_blank" href="http://links.mkt32.net/ui/modules/display/previewFM.jsp" name="fwd_1_1" xt="SPCLICK">Forward to a friend</a>
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table width="660" align="center">
                <tr>
                <td>
                <![endif]-->
      <table class="outer" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <tr>
              <td class="one-column">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="body">
                      <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="category">
                            CATEGORY!
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text" width="100%">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut hendrerit tincidunt finibus. Fusce varius dictum lacus, non mattis magna pulvinar quis. Ut fermentum auctor libero, vitae porta metus fringilla efficitur.
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="full-width-image">
                            <img src="images/HERO_PLACEHOLDER.png" width="600" alt="" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="time">
                            <strong>Title</strong> Weekday, Month Day
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut hendrerit tincidunt finibus. Fusce varius dictum lacus, non mattis magna pulvinar quis. Ut fermentum auctor libero, vitae porta metus fringilla efficitur.
                          </td>
                          <td class="time">
                            <strong>Title</strong> Weekday, Month Day
                          </td>
                          <td class="text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut hendrerit tincidunt finibus. Fusce varius dictum lacus, non mattis magna pulvinar quis. Ut fermentum auctor libero, vitae porta metus fringilla efficitur.
                          </td>
                          <td class="time">
                            <strong>Title</strong> Weekday, Month Day
                          </td>
                          <td class="text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut hendrerit tincidunt finibus. Fusce varius dictum lacus, non mattis magna pulvinar quis. Ut fermentum auctor libero, vitae porta metus fringilla efficitur.
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    </td>
                    </table>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: That example looks much bigger than the [mcve] I would expect for such a question.

Comment: @ovokuro There is a link to the Chrome Inspect screen at the bottom. Does that suffice, or do you need more?

Comment: @TobySpeight Apologies, I am a n00b. I will edit this down as much as I can.

EDIT: Okay, I have cut out all of the other HTML. However, I decided to leave the CSS in case anybody spots anything that could be problematic. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing is setting the value to 282px. You'll note that Chrome shows it as somewhat grayed out; that means that the browser has computed that value without input from CSS. It's computed that value because that's how table cells' widths are calculated; you have 5 columns, and, say 1410px worth of space for the table, so it's going to divide 1410 by 5 and get 282.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code or are you just trying to understand why it's doing this?

Comment: @TylerH There is a problem. It is supposed to be full-width, 660px. Other sections that are laid out and nested identically are full-width. I don't understand why this is happening and I need to know how to stop it. Thanks.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for making my question more clear.

Comment: @Ned so you want the bottom left table cell with the Lorem Ipsum filler text to fill the whole row? Where do you want the other table cells to appear?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/vdm5L3x6/

Comment: @TylerH you nailed it, that's exactly what it's supposed to look like! I'll compare that to what I have. Could you possibly leave an answer explaining how you corrected this? Thanks!

Comment: @NedRedmond An answer would be overkill; I just removed two embedded tables and put each existing `<td>` (table cell) with content in its own `<tr>` (row). Which looks like it's what aletzo did, more or less, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but the problem lies in the 5 `td` tags that you enclose in a table of which all other `tr` tags contain only a single `td` tag:

```
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td class="body">
                  <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="category" colspan="5">
                        CATEGORY!
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text" width="100%">
                        Lorem ipsum ...
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="full-width-image">
                        <img src="images/HERO_PLACEHOLDER.png" width="600" alt="" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="time">
                        <strong>Title</strong> Weekday, Month Day
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text">
                        Lorem ipsum ...
                      </td>
                      <td class="time">
                        <strong>Title</strong> Weekday, Month Day
                      </td>
                      <td class="text">
                        Lorem ipsum ...
                      </td>
                      <td class="time">
                        <strong>Title</strong> Weekday, Month Day
                      </td>
                      <td class="text">
                        Lorem ipsum ...
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </td>    <!-- also these two lines   -->
                </table> <!-- are in the wrong order -->
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Adding the `colspan` attribute could solve this problem. The `td` tags that are alone in `tr` tags should have `colspan="5"` as your last `tr` contains 5 `td`s.

But I think that what you want is to have a single `td` per `tr`, so in that case you could refactor the HTML.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You are correct. I am trying to have one td per tr. I'll try your suggestions and reassess. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure, then, why that doesn't happen to my other sections. The header, introduction, and footer are all set up in the same way with nested <td>s in <tr>s. Colspan sounds like a quick fix, but I would like to know why this is happening now and not in other circumstances.

Comment: @NedRedmond I don't think that I can see your other sections anymore, but I believe that the other sections render as expected because they are inside a new `table` tag, so the 5 `td` tags in the categories `table` don't affect the other tables